# Absolute path in Wordpress Network site

Tags: paths

[This site](http://brinkley.doig.com.au/) is part of a Wordpress Network.

In the theme's CSS, I'd like to reference some font files using @font-face.  The fonts live in the theme's directory.

If I use a path like this:

> http://brinkley.doig.com.au/wp-content/themes/brinkley/myriadpro-boldcond.ttf

, the file is not found.

The true path is

> http://www.doig.com.au/wp-content/themes/brinkley/myriadpro-boldcond.ttf

, but using this path in the CSS does not work (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13357750/font-face-not-working-in-firefox-opera-ie/13377106)).

So, I have the problem of the true path not working in CSS, and the Wordpress network path not being found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a googd practice to write references to files from CSS file using relative path to the theme and not one absolute. So, for instance:

```
background: transparent url('images/sprite_phone.png') no-repeat 0 0;
```

Anyway, on your case there is something wrong with the uploaded file, because none of the paths you give above work.

Comment: The file names had capital letters, while the reference in the CSS file did not.  Thanks.